# Applying a function to columns within a dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

The goal of the below code is to loop through 5 columns of data and apply a function to that row within the column if a condition is met within the 'condition' column.

I have a data frame where I have set up a column as a result of a condition:

```
def WanCon(y):
  if (30 <= y <= 48):
    return 1
  else:
    return 2
time = four70['WY WEEK']
Wandata = pd.DataFrame(time)
Wandata['Condition'] = list(map(WanCon,Wandata['WY WEEK']))
```

I have then copied the values for 5 columns into the new data frame `Wandata` where objects a-e are the x values within my below functions.

```
name = 'WANAP'

a = four40[name]
b = eight40[name]
c = four70[name]
d = eight70[name]
e = Historical[name]

Wandata[['440','840','470','870','Historical']] = [a,b,c,d,e]
Wandata.replace("",float('NaN'),inplace=True)
```

I then have two formula's I would like to apply to the newly added columns based on the above condition where any row in condition where the value is one `Waneq1()` is applied otherwise apply `Waneq2()`:

```
def Waneq1(x):
  return((model1.c[0]*x**3)+(model1.c[1]*x**2)+(model1.c[2]*x)+(model1.c[3]))

def Waneq2(x):
  return((model2.c[0]*x**3)+(model2.c[1]*x**2)+(model2.c[2]*x)+(model2.c[3]))


for column in Wandata[['440','840','470','870','Historical']]:
  if Wandata['Condition']==1:
    Waneq1()
  else:
    Waneq2()
```

Im fairly new to python and this is the farthest I have gotten. I am wondering if any one knows of a better way to achieve this as step three is fairly challenging to me and i've hit a roadblock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what specifically you are trying to do (we also don't know what `four40` etc. objects are), but the right way to apply conditions on a `pandas dataframe` is generally:

```
wandata['output column'] = (model2.c[0]*x**3)+(model2.c[1]*x**2)+(model2.c[2]*x)+(model2.c[3]) # The default value of the column
wandata.loc[wandata['condition'] == 1, 'output columns'] = (model1.c[0]*x**3)+(model1.c[1]*x**2)+(model1.c[2]*x)+(model1.c[3]) # The value if the condition is true
```

Comment: I edited my question but the goal would be to create a loop for the columns in my dataframe which applies the correct function based on the conditional column. Maybe that clears it up? Objects four40, etc are more or less arbitrary however the values in those columns are the inputs into the functions.

Comment: @Aryerex while this method works, it doesnt loop through each of the columns but instead applies the function given the condition for one column at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to my problem by employing an `.apply()` and `lambda` statement within the `df`.

The generalized solution is as below:

`df['f(x)'] = df.apply(lambda r: function1(r['x']) if r['Condition'] == 1 else function2(r['x']), axis=1)`